# Execute a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to execute a .bat file from a command line inside an automation program.  I have written a .bat file that works when double clicked but the automation app will not execute the file.

Is there a command that can be included in the .bat file to make it execute when the automation program calls it up?  Here is the .bat file I wrote:

[LITE BOX HI (BOTH LOW & MEDIUM) - ON]

```
cd..
cd..
cd C:\denkovi\drcltjarorg\
java -jar denkovirelaycommandlinetool.jar DAE001x0 8 4 1
java -jar denkovirelaycommandlinetool.jar DAE001x0 8 6 1
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Ron

Comment: You don't need the `cd ..` lines, since the directory gets set to `C:\denkovi\drcltjarorg` regardless of what directory you were previously in. Also, how are you using the automation app to call the script (and more importantly, which automation app are you using)?

Comment: You might need to run `cmd.exe /c c:\path\to\file.bat`. In the batch file use `cd /d C:\denkovi\drcltjarorg\ ` to be sure.

Comment: The automation app is "CCDAutoPilot" that has entry points for external commands.  Running on Win7 Pro.

Comment: Please see the revised .bat file based on the suggestions:  [LITE BOX LOW - ON]

cmd.exe /c:\Denkovi\Batch Files

cd /d C:\denkovi\drcltjarorg\
java -jar denkovirelaycommandlinetool.jar DAE001x0 8 4 1  This file also works when double clicked on but does not work when entered in the automation app entry point.

Answer (score 0):

First try adding "pause" to the bottom of the BAT script to see if there are any errors.

Also verify if the path of the executable you are calling is in the PATH variable for the computer.

Make sure the relevant JAR's are in the correct directory.

Comment: [LITE BOX LOW - ON]

cmd.exe /c:\Denkovi\Batch Files

cd /d C:\denkovi\drcltjarorg\
java -jar denkovirelaycommandlinetool.jar DAE001x0 8 4 1

pause                                           NxtLevel:  I added the "pause" and gave it a try by double clicking the file and it worked fine but it does not work when placed in the script entry line in the automation app.  Thanks for your reply.  Ron

Comment: Try using the full path of java.exe and the full path of the JAR file in the batch script, this should definitely execute. Also attempt to see if the automation program has any error logs or such for pointers on what might be wrong...